# Delphi - Detect pressing 3 keys at the same time

Tags: delphi

I want to detect pressing 3 keys in my form for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>...the typed form I need to detect will always begin with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and next come two letters.

How I do that ?

Comment: Use a `TActionManager`

Comment: @Jerry that won't help

Comment: @David Ahh limitations from multiple letter keys?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On arrival of one of the keys, you can look if the other key already has been down. E.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Shift = [ssCtrl] then begin
    case Key of
      Ord('C'):
        if (GetKeyState(Ord('N')) and $80) = $80 then
          ShowMessage('combo');
      Ord('N'):
        if (GetKeyState(Ord('C')) and $80) = $80 then
          ShowMessage('combo');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However this will also detect for instance <kbd>N</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, a sequence which does not begin with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. If this doesn't qualify as a valid key combination, you can keep a bit of key history with the help of a flag. The following should only detect sequences that initially begins with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  private
    FValidKeyCombo: Boolean;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if FValidKeyCombo and (Shift = [ssCtrl]) then
    case Key of
      Ord('C'):
        if (GetKeyState(Ord('N')) and $80) = $80 then
          ShowMessage('combo');
      Ord('N'):
        if (GetKeyState(Ord('C')) and $80) = $80 then
          ShowMessage('combo');
    end;
  FValidKeyCombo := (Shift = [ssCtrl]) and (Key in [Ord('C'), Ord('N')]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  FValidKeyCombo := False;
end;
```

Comment: I found that if I want to make Ctrl+C+N respond in same order I must use 'N' with `case key of` and test 'C' with `GetKeyState`....why is that behavior ?

Comment: @Well - You're welcome. If the 'N' will be the last key, then when the event handler is running for 'N' down, 'C' should have already been pressed. That's what we are checking with 'GetKeyState', if 'C' is down.

Answer (score 4):

There is more easy way:

```
    procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;  Shift: TShiftState);
     begin
         If (GetKeyState(Ord('Q'))<0) and (GetKeyState(Ord('N'))<0) and (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)<0)
           Then ShowMessage('You did it :)');
     End;
```

Comment: You won't know if the first pressed key is 'ctrl' or one of the others.. Additionally, this will still qualify when you press a completely different key after you've pressed the three of them.